# How does one get setfacl to set ACL permissions recursively on Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm setting up a new server and wanted to give ACL a shot over the chown:chgrp:chmod style permissions.

The man page for setfacl indicates that the '-R' option can be used to set the ACL recursively on files and directories.

> -R, --recursive
>     Apply operations to all files and directories recursively. This option cannot be mixed with
>   ‘--restore’.

If my directory layout looks like this

> ```
> test/
>    subtest/
>    subtest.txt
> ```

and I execute

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:foo:rwX test
```

The ACL takes effect on the 'subtest' directory, but not the subtest.txt file.

I think I can use find + exec to workaround it, but I plan to use this server to train a few other admin and I am wanting to keep it as simple as possible so we don't get hung up on some of the more advanced conventions.

Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try:

```
setfacl --recursive --modify u:foo:rwX,d:u:foo:rwX test
```

to modify the current ACL as well as the default. I believe "d:" only affects the (d)efault ACL of directories and leaves files untouched. Then, if you create a **new** file in the directory, it inherits the ACL of its parent directory via the default.

Comment: That makes sense even if it feels a bit redundant

Comment: Does this work for removing access control as well. Perhaps something to the effect of: sudo setfacl -Rx g:gid path

Comment: why does changing places between the `-R` and `-m` flags breaks the command?

Comment: @pkaramol: Because the `-m` option takes an argument (the ACL spec `u:foo:rwX,d:u:foo:rwX` in this case) and switching the order of the options separates the option from its argument. It may also be that `setfacl` is coded to expect its main options first.

Comment: More readable version of command: `setfacl --recursive --modify user:foo:rwX,default:user:foo:rwX test`. Today I learned the capital X is important for setting the eXecute permission for just folders and not every single file. Lower-case x sets the execute permission for folders and files.